# Are these MySQL Abstraction Classes safe from SQL Injection?  Can they be made safe?

Tags: php, mvc

I was looking at this website:

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Creating-User-Models-in-PHP-and-MySQL/1/
and
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Creating-User-Models-in-PHP-and-MySQL/2/

In the first one they have methods such as:

```
/**
     * Perform a SELECT statement
     */ 
    public function select($table, $where = '', $fields = '*', $order = '', $limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        $query = 'SELECT ' . $fields . ' FROM ' . $table
               . (($where) ? ' WHERE ' . $where : '')
               . (($limit) ? ' LIMIT ' . $limit : '')
               . (($offset && $limit) ? ' OFFSET ' . $offset : '')
               . (($order) ? ' ORDER BY ' . $order : '');
        $this->query($query);
        return $this->countRows();
    }

    /**
     * Perform an INSERT statement
     */  
    public function insert($table, array $data)
    {
        $fields = implode(',', array_keys($data));
        $values = implode(',', array_map(array($this, 'quoteValue'), array_values($data)));
        $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . '(' . $fields . ')' . ' VALUES (' . $values . ')';
        $this->query($query);
        return $this->getInsertId();
    }
```

then in the second page:

```
/**
     * Fetch all users
     */
    public function fetchAll()
    {
        // try to fetch users data from the cache system
        if ($users = $this->_cache->get('all')) {
            return $users;
        }
        // otherwise fecth users data from the database
        $this->_adapter->select('users');
        $users = array();
        while ($user = $this->_adapter->fetch()) {
            $users[] = $user;
        }
        if (count($users) !== 0) {
           $this->_cache->set('all', $users); 
        }
        return $users;
    }

    /**
     * Insert new user data (the cache is cleared also)
     */
    public function insert(array $data)
    {
        if ($insertId = $this->_adapter->insert('users', $data)) {
            $this->_cache->clear();
            return $insertId;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Delete the table row corresponding to the specified user (the cache is cleared also)
     */ 
    public function delete($id)
    {
        if ($affectedRow = $this->_adapter->delete('users', "id = $id")) {
            $this->_cache->clear();
            return $affectedRow; 
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Is this a bad way of doing things?  Is this opening me up to sql injection just like anything else where I construct the sql on the fly would?  I want to build my models "right."  Does that mean I need to have all stored procedures or prepared statements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: That's not a duplicate.  I'll edit the title of this one to clarify.

Comment: I can't see where your parameters are coming from, but *theoretically* as long as you are escaping them properly you should be ok.

Comment: Don't do it this way, better to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) and parameterise your queries. There is a good tutorial here http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers. Also take a look at the information in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You may be right, but there's still some good information there for the OP. In fact, I think the accepted answer there could answer this question. Don't you?

Comment: Also take a look at this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5887401/212940

Comment: Get yourself some redbean, then use prepared statements. http://redbeanphp.com/

Comment: I don't know why SO keeps sending these kinds of things over this way. This isn't a code review, this is a legitimate question about implementation. Also, I'm not sure where the authors of those articles over at DevShed stand on the matter, but blatantly copying their work is considered copyright infringement. I think the policy on including code from linked websites only extends to your own code.

Comment: @showerhead I don't know about devshed, but I know that when I posted just a link on SO, I was thrashed and given a -6.  I was told by one commenter they "frankly did not care" but if I wanted an answer to post code.  So, here I did and gave a link.

Comment: @johnny: Sadly a lot of people don't understand that you don't always HAVE the code yourself and what you are asking about is a "theory". I understand the frustration. Just beware of copyright. Usually authors don't mind you sampling their work as long as you aren't claiming it as your own and cite them. Not sure why my comment from yesterday seemed to be implying that you weren't doing this, guess it was just a long day, sorry if you took that the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

[Active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) instances are not "models". They are anti-patterns which RoR likes call that way. And what you are implementing there is an active record.

And no, those queries are not safe. They are wide open for SQL injection, because, instead of using proper SQL [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), you opted for concatenation.

As for build building model, you have to understand that **model is a layer**. One of two in MVC. The other being - presentation layer (made of controllers, views and templates). You might read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208), but I am no sure how much of it you will be able to assimilate.

I think your first priority should be to read the [hashphp PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) and then watching the list if lecture that you can find a the bottom of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855170/727208). And only then try another stab at the whole "mvc thing".